# I want to know theoretical thing about programming

Tags: object, methods, constructor

I'm not sure about one thing. There are two things in object oriented programming.

1. Constructor
2. Method

Which one of these can be overloaded and which one overridden?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both can be overloaded. 
overloading means having two or more methods or constructors with exactly same name but different signatures. some thing like :

> ```
> public myClass(String a){}
> public myClass(Double d){}
> ```

or for methods :

> ```
> public void aMethod(String s){}
> publis int aMethod(Double d){
> return 0;
> }
> ```

edited :
bebin, overriding usually comes with inheritance , when the super class implements a method but the subclass needs to implement that method in other way like :
in super class:

> ```
> public int doSomething(){
>   return a+2;
> }
> ```

but in subclass :

> ```
> @override
> public in doSomething(){
> return a*2;
> }
> ```

and about constructor overriding the following line are from CollinD and i am quoting it :
"Constructors are not normal methods and they cannot be "overridden". Saying that a constructor can be overridden would imply that a superclass constructor would be visible and could be called to create an instance of a subclass. This isn't true... a subclass doesn't have any constructors by default (except a no-arg constructor if the class it extends has one). It has to explicitly declare any other constructors, and those constructors belong to it and not to its superclass, even if they take the same parameters that the superclass constructors take.

The stuff you mention about default no arg constructors is just an aspect of how constructors work and has nothing to do with overriding."

Comment: Yeh I Studied About that  But please read Comment Above.. I Ask A Situational Question. And What About Overridden ?? And What is it ? I Really Didn't Study about that can you please explain With Example I'm thanksful to you :)

Comment: i edited the post but i think you have found your answer. just for feature googlers

Comment: Thanks This Is More appropriate One Than Previous thanks Alot :)

Answer (score 1):

That may depend on the language, but theoretically both can be both overloaded and overridden.

C# examples of everything:

```
class Parent {
    protected string Name;

    public Parent(string name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public Parent(string firstName, string lastName) {
        this.Name = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public virtual string GetName() {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
    public Child(string firstName) : base(firstName, "Doe") {}

    public override string GetName() {
        return this.Name = " Jr.";
    }

    public string GetName(string prefix) {
        return prefix + " " + this.GetName();
    }
}
```

This illustrates constructor and method overriding and constructor and method overloading.

Comment: No man I'm confirmed that constructor can't overridden :) but not sure about method

Comment: @AliRaza: PHP begs to differ :) Do you have a particular language in mind?

Comment: @AliRaza Constructors can be overriden in a variety of languages. Python is another example.

Comment: @AliRaza: In fact, they're also implicitly overridden in C# and VB.NET if no paramaterless constructor is provided.

Comment: Php Is scripting Language Although It Object Oriented but instead its a scripting language but over than that In C# Or C++ ?? can you tell me about that ?

Comment: Why does it matter that PHP is a scripting language?

Comment: Ok Let Me Clear One thing I Have In A Test today that Which One Of The Follwing Can Be Overridden? and There are four options and method and constructor are two of them So what Should I Select ?

Comment: One More question Which One Can Overload And Again four options and two them is method and constructor and i have to select one of them :s in both cases

Comment: @AliRaza: Demo added. Also, don't rush us, we're just trying to help. It's not our fault the test is today :)

Comment: @minitech Dear I'm Not rushing. just want to confirm. and my test had been conducted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can overload and override both constructors and methods. (I think constructors are really just a special kind of method.)

Overriding allows a subclass to replace the implementation of its parent class.

Overloading allows you to create a different versions of a method that take different parameter lists.